# python extract part from a list of paths

Tags: python, list

I've got a list of path from a folder, so I have:

1. `folder/subfolder1/file1`
2. `folder/subfolder1/file2`
3. `folder/subfolder2/file1`
4. `folder/subfolder2/file2`
5. `folder/subfolder3/file1`
6. `folder/subfolder3/file2`

etc.

From this list of path I want iteratively extract the element `file1`, `file2`, `file1`, `file2` from my first list as a separate list. It's always the `element [2]` but I'm not understanding how to iterate

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you can create a list of the file names like this

```
import os
list_of_filenames = [os.path.basename(x) for x in list_of_paths]
```

that will produce a list of consisting on ["file1","file2","file1"...]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution:

```
# let's first create this function
import os, sys
def splitall(path):
    allparts = []
    while 1:
        parts = os.path.split(path)
        if parts[0] == path:  
            allparts.insert(0, parts[0])
            break
        elif parts[1] == path: 
            allparts.insert(0, parts[1])
            break
        else:
            path = parts[0]
            allparts.insert(0, parts[1])
    return allparts

# then:

cl = []

for i in list:
    cl.append(splitall(i)[1])

# [1] it's the element position
```